# KnockoutJS - Adding computed values to an observable array

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm binding data to a page using KnockoutJS, the ViewModel is being populated by an JSON response from an AJAX call using the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("Get")", 
        function(allData) {
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(allData);

            viewModel.Brokers.Url = ko.computed(function()
            {
                return 'BASEURLHERE/' + this.BrokerNum();
            });

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
});
```

The middle part there doesn't work (it works fine without that computed property). "Brokers" is an observable array, and I want to add a computed value to every element in the array called URL. I'm binding that Brokers array to a foreach, and I'd like to use that URL as the `href` attribute of an anchor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, if you want Url in each broker, you have to add it to each broker:

```
$.each(viewModel.Brokers(), function(index, broker){
    broker.Url = ko.computed(function(){return 'BASEURLHERE/' + broker.BrokerNum();});
});
```

I guess BrokerNum is not going to change, so you might as well just calculate Url once:

```
$.each(viewModel.Brokers(), function(index, broker){
    broker.Url = 'BASEURLHERE/' + broker.BrokerNum();
});
```

You can also add Url property during mapping by providing "create" callback to ko.mapping.fromJS function. See [mapping plugin docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for details.

If you only need url to bind to href, just bind the expression in html (within foreach binding):

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: 'BASEURLHERE/' + BrokerNum()}">link to broker details</a>
```

Answer (score 13):

I've been working through very similar issues and I've found that you can intercept the creation of the Broker objects and insert your own fields using the mapping options parameter:

```
var data = { "Brokers":[{"BrokerNum": "2"},{"BrokerNum": "10"}] };

var mappingOptions = {
    'Brokers': {
        create: function(options) {
            return (new (function() {
                this.Url = ko.computed(function() {
                    return 'http://BASEURLHERE/' + this.BrokerNum();
                }, this);

                ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this); // continue the std mapping
            })());
        }
    }
};

viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/pwiles/ZP2pg/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter Wiles i have very similar solution:

```
var ViewModel = function (data, ranges) {
    var self = this;

    this.productList = ko.observableArray();
    var productListMapping = {
        create: function (options) {
            return (new (function () {
            //this row above i don't understand...
                this.len = ko.computed(function () {
                    //just test function returning lenght of object name
                    // and one property of this model
                    return this.name().length + ' ' + self.cons_slider_1();
                }, this);

                ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this); // continue the std mapping
            })());
        }
    }

    this.cons_slider_1 = ko.observable(100);

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, productListMapping, this.productList);
};
```

Some differences:
I am not mapping to self, but on this.product.
The input json has not parent name like 'Brokers' in above example:

```
var products = [
    { "id": "pp1", "name": "Blue windy" },
    { "id": "pp1", "name": "Blue windy" }];
```

So in productMapping i'm typing just 'create:'

But, what i do not understand is the structure of create function. Could somebody explain me why the function returns new function, which has property. Couldn't it be simplified somehow?